# Binding input field on a single div click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this:

```
<td>
    <div></div>
    <input hidden>
</td>
...
<td>
    <div></div>
    <input hidden>
</td>
```

When I click the div, I want to hide the div and bind the input and so:

```
$(document).one("click", 'div',function(){
    $(input).bind('blur keyup',function(e) {
            ....
```

BUT apparently the input gets bind only when I click IN the input again to edit it.

As a result I can click on multiple divs and not bind any of them.

How Can I click on a div and bind the input field without having to click the input field first ?!

Comment: Can you post the code you have come up with atleast a working snippet so we could see what's wrong with it?

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do, but using `$(this).find('input')` will probably help

Comment: @Highdef No, but are you saying that in general it should be working ?

Comment: @Hartun Can't say until we can see what's wrong with your code exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    var current_input = $(this).next('input')
    current_input.css('display', 'block')

    if (current_input.val())
      alert('Entered Value "' + current_input.val() + '"')
    current_input.focus()
  });
});
```

```css
.divi {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="divi">Div 1</div>
          <input hidden>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="divi">Div 2</div>
          <input hidden>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think it might be close to what the OP asked but just hide the div as well on click like it has been mentioned. ( $(this).hide(); in your function when div is clicked)

Comment: sorry.I forgot to hide the div ..you have to add click function inside $(this).hide() at the end of the line

Comment: OK, not quite what I needed but the important thing was the focus() which resolved my problem, thank you :)